# how to embed a function to column in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, generated-columns

I'm new to SQL and PostgreSQL and I'm trying to find a way to create a new table in database where a column will automatically calculate a pre-defined function with data from other columns.

Specifically I want a **LOG** table with
**TIME_IN | TIME_OUT | DURATION** columns
where the DURATION column shows the result of (`=TIME_OUT - TIME_IN`)

Of course this can be done with running a query but I'm trying to figure out if it's possible

to have it pre-defined so whenever running `SELECT * FROM log`
the table will load up with duration value already calculated according to updated data in **IN / OUT** columns.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using a [generated column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html), e.g.:

```
create table log
( 
  id integer primary key generated always as identity,
  time_in timestamp,
  time_out timestamp,
  duration interval generated always as (time_out - time_in) stored
);
```

Another option would be to create a [view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html):

```
create view log_with_duration
as
select id, 
       time_in, 
       time_out, 
       time_out - time_in as duration
from log;
```